# How to get value from <div>value</div>?

Tags: php, domdocument

I need to get value from

```
<div id = "result">Roll No 103 Pass</div>
```

and out put should be : Roll No 103 Pass

I used this code :

```
$markup = file_get_contents('www.results.com');
$doc = new DomDocument();
@$file = $doc->loadHTML($markup);
$spans = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($spans AS $span)
    {
    $class = $span -> getElementsById('id');
    if($class=="result") { 
        echo $span -> nodeValue;


    }


}
```

but it just return blank screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.results.com');
$thediv = $doc->getElementById('result');
echo $thediv->textContent;
```

Answer (score 2):

Two remarks:

1. IDs have to be unique, so there is little sense in looping over elements and search for an element with a specific ID in them. Just get the element directly.
2. You can get the inner text with the [`textContent` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) property.

Example:

```
$div = $doc->getElementById('result');
if($div) {
    echo $div->textContent;
}
```