# Finding div class value using php simple html dom or phpQuery

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

I'm trying to get a hang of php simple html dom and I'm having some issues when it comes to div classes.

For example, say on newegg I want to find the value of the div class'skiplink' (I just picked a random class on the site). According to the php simple html dom documentation found [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) I should just use.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.newegg.com');

print_r($ret = $html->find('.skiplink'));
```

Right now it just hangs and seems to freeze. I know the installation is working because the following code works.

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
   echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Basically, how can I look at a specific div class on a given website and find that value?

Is there an easier way to do this, such as with phpQuery

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($html->find('.skiplink'));`?

Comment: why dont just use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) ??

Comment: @AlfredXing chrome crashes on me when I try that.

Comment: @Charlie how would I use it specifically with what I'm trying to do (finding the value of a given div class)

Answer (score 0):

From a simple search on this site: [How to get value from <div>value</div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383396/how-to-get-value-from-divvalue-div)

But here is what they say;

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.results.com');
$thediv = $doc->getElementById('result');
echo $thediv->textContent;
```

Or you can find the innerText value of your div clause by grabbing its value by id;

```
$div = $doc->getElementById('result');
if($div) {
    echo $div->textContent;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting errors for just about everything I try. Say I want to find the price of the item found [here](http://www.newegg.com/Special/ShellShocker.aspx?cm_sp=ShellShocker-_-32-562-001-_-04062013_1) on newegg. The id of it is ltFrequentlyBoughtItemFinalPrice0 . When I use the code you showed I get a bunch of errors such as "Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'"

Answer (score 0):

OR use XPath instead, this code will out put the src

```
//init DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
//get the source from the URL
$html = file_get_contents("URL");
//load the html
dom->loadHTML($html);
//init XPath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//fetch the src from the iframe within a class name
$iframe_src=$xpath->query('//*[@class="CLASSNAME"]/iframe//@src');

vardump($iframe_src);
```

To get the contents use `file_get_contents()`

```
$options  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'USERAGENT')); //you must specify a user agent
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($iframe_src, false, $context);
```